# Is it possible to manually manage a Solid State Hybrid Drive?

Tags: linux, storage, ssd, ssd-hdd-hybrid

I'm about to buy a new laptop which has a SSHD. It stands for Solid State Hybrid Drive, which means it has a big, regular HDD with a small, usually 8GB SSD to cache frequently accessed files.

Now since I'm a Linux user and I want pure SSD speed, so I thought it would be awesome if I could detach the SSD from the HDD and use it completely separate.
I've googled for this topic, but could not find anything useful. According to Wikipedia there is a standard to communicate with the drives separately, but I may have misunderstood.

Does anyone know anything about this topic?

Comment: The tag sshd shouldn't be used here, I understand the difference you're portraying w/ SSHD vs. SSD but `sshd` is the name of the SSH daemon, and that's a more on topic item on this site.

Comment: My sense (and a quick Google search) is that those hybrid drives with a SSD cache are a black box and there's no way to directly access the SSD; it would be like trying to directly access a CPU cache.

Comment: What wikipedia article are you talking of? Please add a link in your question.

Comment: The one you linked in your answer, so you found it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wikipedia article goes on to say that in some cases it is possible to manage the SSHD cache from the host:

> SSHD products operate in two primary modes:
>
> Self-optimized mode
>       In this mode of operation, the SSHD works independently from the host operating system or host device drives to make all decisions
>   related to identifying data that will be stored in NAND flash memory.
>   This mode results in a storage product that appears and operates to a
>   host system exactly as a traditional hard drive would.
>
> Host-optimized mode (or host-pinning mode)
>       In this mode of operation, the SSHD enables an extended set of SATA commands defined in the Hybrid Information feature of the Serial
>   ATA International Organization standards for the SATA interface. Using
>   this feature, decisions about which data elements are placed in the
>   NAND flash memory come from the host operating system, device drivers,
>   host software or a combination of these host level components.

A little bit of googling tells me that [patches](https://www.mail-archive.com/linux-kernel@vger.kernel.org/msg755038.html) to make use of the hybrid information feature from [SerialATA Revision 3.2](http://www.knowledgetek.com/graphicsNew/SerialATA_Revision_3_2_Gold%28with%20Links%29.pdf) section 13.20 have been submitted for review, and that host pinning support may be merged in at the earliest to the 3.19 release.

Answer (score 2):

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_drive there are two different types of hybrid disk "dual drives" with separate manageable disks and integrated SSHDs which cannot be used separately.

[image]

Comment: Likely the one in the laptop is the second type. I'm sad to hear that it can't be used separately.